Strict bound for recurrence formula
Given the recurrence $$T(n) = (2k - 1)T(\frac{n}{k})+2^kn$$ I need to show (or disprove) that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $k$ such that $T(n)=o(n^{1+\epsilon})$.
So far, I've been able to conclude the following:
For a fixed $k$, I'll use the master's theorem: $f(n) = 2^kn, a = 2k-1, b=k, log_b(a)=log_k(2k-1)$.
Thus, this matches case 1 of the master theorem: we can choose a small enough $\delta>0$ such that $$f(n)=2^kn=O(n)=O(n^{log_k(2k-1)-\delta})$$ since $log_k(2k-1)>1$ for $k\geq2$. So by the master's theorem, I get $T(n)=\Theta(n^{log_k(2k-1)})$. But now I am not sure how to continue. I'd try showing that given an $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $k$ such that $T(n)=\Theta(n^{log_k(2k-1)})=o(n^{1+\epsilon})$ using the limit definition of $o$, but I am not really sure how to take that limit, since the numerator term will be a $\Theta$ of something.
Thanks in advance.

So, that recurrence is supposed to work for all $k?$

Yes for all k it is supposed to work

It can't be literally true for all $k,$ since then  $$T(n)=(2k^2-1)T(n/k^2)+2^{k^2}n,$$ and applying twice gives: $$T(n)=(2k-1)T(n/k)+2^kn=(2k-1)\left((2k-1)T(n/k^2)+2^kn/k\right)+2^kn\
=(2k-1)^2 T(n/k^2)+2^kn\left(\frac{(2k-1)}k+1\right)$$ You might be able to satisfy $$T(n)\leq \dots$$
